# Change EXIF data on JPEG without altering picture

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I change the exif on a jpeg using piexif to read and write exif data, which seems to work fine. The issue is when I read and write the jpeg, even tho I don't change the bytes, it saves the picture with different pixels and the picture that was read. I need it to be exactly the same pixels. I understand this is because jpeg is a lossy format, but the only way I've found around it is to save it as a png and then export it as a jpeg with Mac Preview, which is not good, because I have hundreds of pictures.

```
def adjust_img(path):
   img = PIL.Image.open(path)
   exif_dict = piexif.load(img.info['exif'])
   new_exif = adjust_exif(exif_dict)
   exif_bytes = piexif.dump(new_exif)
   pc = path.split('/')
   stem = '/'.join(pc[:-1])
   img.save('%s/_%s' % (stem,pc[-1]), "JPEG", exif=exif_bytes, quality=95, optimize=False)
```

How can I preserve the picture and just alter the exif?

Comment: Use `exiftool`. Install via **homebrew** with `brew install exiftool`

Comment: Ended up using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html

```
exif_dict = piexif.load(path)
new_exif = adjust_exif(exif_dict)
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(new_exif)
piexif.insert(exif_bytes, path)
```

Comment: If you've searched your way here, be careful before using this library.  It hasn't been updated in years and has a lot of open issues.  I wouldn't trust it to modify user files without a lot of testing.

Answer (score 9):

Exiftool is generally the way to go.  But suppose you really need to edit EXIFs in your own program?

Try pyexiv2 at https://pypi.org/project/pyexiv2/.
It is recently maintained and working well.  An example:

```
import sys
from pyexiv2 import Image as ImgMeta

DTO_KEY = 'Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal'
filename = sys.argv[1]


with ImgMeta(filename) as img_meta:

    exif = img_meta.read_exif()
    try:
        dto = exif[DTO_KEY]
    except KeyError:
        raise

    # Convert dto to DateTime, add TimeDelta, format as string
    # Here we skip all that to show we can simply modify it:
    new_dto_str = dto + 'Z'

    img_meta.modify_exif({DTO_KEY: new_dto_str})
```

When I use this I typically do the edits on a backup copy, then move it into place if happy with it.